# Cropping a UIImage according to the viewport inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, resize, core-graphics, crop

I have a UIImageView (initialized with Aspect Fill) inside a UIScrollView.
The user shall use that to resize and position a UIImage to his like, press a button and then exactly what he sees on screen would be sent to a server, only in the original image coordinates. In other words, the resulting image would be bigger than the image on screen.

Here's the essential part of my code so far:

```
// select the original 
CGFloat imageRatio = self.imageView.image.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.height;    
CGFloat viewRatio  = self.imageView.frame.size.width / self.imageView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat scale;

// get the scale factor of the image being "aspect-filled"
if(imageRatio < viewRatio) {
    scale = self.imageView.image.size.width / self.imageView.frame.size.width;
} else {
    scale = self.imageView.image.size.height / self.imageView.frame.size.height;
}

// get the cropping origin in the image's original coordinates
CGFloat originX = self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
CGFloat originY = self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.y * scale;
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(originX, originY);

// get the cropping size in the image's original coordinates
CGFloat width  = self.imageView.image.size.width  / self.imageScrollView.zoomScale;
CGFloat height = self.imageView.image.size.height / self.imageScrollView.zoomScale;
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);

// create the new image from the original one
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, size.width, size.height);
struct CGImage *croppedCGImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.imageView.image.CGImage, imageRect);
```

It already looks **quite** close to what I want. The origin calculation at least seems correct. However, there is still some difference in the resulting image, which I guess comes from the different aspect ratios of the possible images. Probably I need to add `scale` to my `size` equations somehow, but I seriously just can't wrap my head around **how**.

Hopefully somebody can help me get this last two meters...

**[EDIT]**

According to the first comment, I tried out the following. But somehow my `targetFrame` is always identical to `scrollFrame`. Is it simply too late at night for me to get something right??

```
CGFloat zoom = self.imageScrollView.zoomScale;
// the full image resolution
CGRect fullImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                   self.imageView.image.size.width,
                                   self.imageView.image.size.height);
UIView *fullImageView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:fullImageFrame] autorelease];
// the theoretical size of the image on the screen
CGRect previewImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                      self.imageView.frame.size.width * zoom,
                                      self.imageView.frame.size.height * zoom);
UIView *previewImageView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:previewImageFrame] autorelease];
// the excerpt of previewImageFrame really visible
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.x,
                                self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width,
                                self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height);
// that excerpt transferred to the full resolution image's coordinates
CGRect targetFrame = [fullImageView convertRect:scrollFrame fromView:previewImageView];
```

Comment: could you please post your final solution? I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem, tried similar way, but its never 100% accurate (sometimes the offset of x position is smaller than it should be).

Comment: Did anyone ever get the final solution to @Dennis problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to explore:

```
(CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view
```

This and other similar methods allow you to take a view and adjust its coordinate system based on placement in a superview other than the one it was initially intended or positioned for.

Comment: I'll try to play around with it, but on my first impression it seems that it's not really suitable for my case since I have to work with offsets of the UIScrollView and also the image in my UIImageView typically has all different dimensions than the frame.

Comment: Either I misunderstood how that method is supposed to work or I did something wrong again... Just updated my original post with a new version.

Comment: Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868288/getting-the-visible-rect-of-an-uiscrollviews-content

Comment: That at least sent me on the right track, thanks. I had to change the maths slightly, but the main problem was that I calculated using `frame` where I should have used `bounds`. So even the right math couldn't have worked before.

Comment: Thanks for the example... (sarcasm)

Comment: @Dennis did you ever come up with a totally working solution? I tried your code but had the same problem and am switching to bounds instead, eh just noticed that this doesnt return a cropped uiimage at all