# Detecting which of several UIViews is displayed in paging UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with ten `UIView`s in it and paging enabled. On `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` I want to decide which of the child `UIView`s is being displayed in the scroll view's frame.

I was going to check the top-left and bottom-right of each view to make sure that both points are in the scroll view's frame, but that seems like a less-efficient way.

Is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868288/getting-the-visible-rect-of-an-uiscrollviews-content

Comment: @janusfidel That is certainly a helpful first step. Thank You.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you have enabled paging in scroll view, the maximum visible view will be automatically adjusted to full view.

Comment: @cocoakomali I want to change another part of the application depending on which view they switch to, but I need to know the active view before I can do that.

Comment: In order to do that, you can take the scroll view's content offset after scrolling and calculate it's position. I will give sample code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is from an assumption that it's an iphone app in portrait orientation.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     int page= floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - 320/2) / 320)+1  ;
}
```

Comment: I did a variation of this, so you can have the prize!