# How to get scroll views visible rectangle frame after it scrolls in IOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I cannot get the coordinates of visible rectangle in scroll view after şt scrolls. So when I want to add a subview in a visible rect, I cannot. How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you?  The visible rect has an origin of scrollview.contentOffset size of scrollview.bounds.size

Answer (score 5):

```
CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(myScrollView.contentOffset.x, myScrollView.contentOffset.y, myScrollView.contentOffset.x + myScrollView.bounds.size.width, myScrollView.contentOffset.y + myScrollView.bounds.size.height)
```

This should get you the `rect` that is currently visible, after scrolling.
Not what you must decide is, when you want to calculate the rect. If you want to get this on the fly, then do it in the`scrollViewDidScroll` method. If you want to get it when user begins scrolling, then do it in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`. If you want it after the user is done scrolling and the `scrollView` comes to rest, do it in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.

Comment: The size is incorrect in your answer. You don't add the offset to the size.

Answer (score 3):

The visible rect of a scrollView at all time is as below:

```
CGRectMake(scrollview.contentOffset.x, scrollview.contentOffset.y, scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Note, this is correct, but can be simplified to `scrollview.bounds`. For `UIScrollView` the origin of the bounds is the content offset. Also, this is only correct for zoomScale = 1. If zoomed, you must transform the rect to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

The visible rect for a `UIScrollView` is `myScrollView.bounds`. There is no need to use `CGRectMake` or use the `contentOffset` property, as the other answers suggest (although it does get you to the same place). However, if the scroll view allows zooming, then you need to transform the rect to account for zooming. A number of solutions for applying the transform are provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868288/getting-the-visible-rect-of-an-uiscrollviews-content).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about what you are asking, but if you need to get the content offset *as* it is being scrolled, you can just use the delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

which will be invoked every time the contentOffset changes.

Alternatively you could use

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

to know the `contentOffset` of the scrollview the seconds it stops decelerating.

Or

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

to know the `contentOffset` of the scrollview when the user stops panning it around.