# How to check if UIScrollView stopped scrolling at a specific ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a vertical UIScrollView that has a StackView in which View Controllers are added to and each View Controller is of a different size.

If scrolling stopped at a specific View Controller (the 3rd one out of five View Controllers), I want to show a tooltip within it.

I already tried checking the scrollview content offset or the view controller's frame.origin.x position but this x position is always returned as 0

How do I know if this specific view controller is now visible to the user (scrollview stopped at it) in ScrollViewWillEndDragging?

Comment: You can find helpful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868288/getting-the-visible-rect-of-an-uiscrollviews-content)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 5 view controller and below are the heights.

```
V1 = 100
V2 = 200
V3 = 300
V4 = 400
V5 = 500
```

Now add a delegate for scrollview and keep an eye on `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("y position==\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
}
```

now based on `scrollView.contentOffset.y`, you can find out that which view controller is visible.

E.x.

For first

```
If scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 100, still first is going
```

For second

```
If scrollView.contentOffset.y >100 && scrollView.contentOffset.y <=(100+200), second one is visible
```

and so on